# No gaussian shape after log transformation and scaling

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, mathematical-statistics, clustering, data-transformation

I have customer purchase history data which has variables like `recency`, `frequency` and `monetary value`.

Like any business, most of our revenue comes only from 20% of the customers. So, our distributions for each of the variables are skewed.

As I intend to use them in k-means algorithm for clustering, I wanted to do the below preprocessing steps

a) Log transformation

b) Standard scaler or Min Max scaler etc.

However, I found out that except monetary value (which is transformed into normal distribution shape), the other two variables `recency` and `frequency` are not able to be transformed into gaussian distribution.

They look like below.

So, my question is, what should we do if the variables are not converted to gaussian shape (ever after preprocessing)? Can we use them in clustering? Is there any other preprocessing steps that we should continue applying until we get gaussian shape? But I don't know this graph behavior is expected (becuase that's how our business functions - 80:20 rule). But they are not in gaussian shape. So, can we use them in clustering with this skewness?

**recency graph**  - recency indicates how recently (in days) did the customer make a purchase?

Before transformation

[image]

After transformation (log and standard scaling)

[image]

**frequency graph** - frequency indicates how many times did the customer buy from us?

Before transformation

[image]

After transformation (log and standard scaling)

[image]

Comment: Isn't the entire point of clustering to detect and characterize distributions that are *far* from Gaussian (or any other standard simple shape)??

Comment: @whuber - then why are we expected to preprocess (transform distribution shape) before we feed it as input into kmeans?

Comment: You aren't -- but it's always an option.  Different ways of expressing your variables can uncover different kinds of relationships.  Clustering tends to be exploratory in nature: it's a search for patterns.  You look for them any way you can.